# How to render React providers recursively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I have `n` number of provider components, which are providing context for my MobX stores:

```
function App({ children }) {
  const owner = createStore(() => OwnerStore);
  const OwnerProvider = useProvider(OwnerStoreID);

  const cat = createStore(() => CatStore);
  const CatProvider = useProvider(CatStoreID);

  return (
    <OwnerProvider value={owner}>
      <CatProvider value={cat}>
        {children}
      </CatProvider>
    </OwnerProvider>
  );
}
```

However, the number of distinct stores in my application is actually in the dozens, and I don't want to maintain a Christmas tree of nested providers.

I have attempted to write something like this:

```
const storesConfig = [
  {
    store: OwnerStoreID,
    id: OwnerStoreID,
  },
]

export const StoresProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const createdStores = storesConfig.map((storeConfig) =>
    createStore(() => storeConfig.store)
  )
  const createdProviders = storesConfig.map((storeConfig) =>
    useProvider(storeConfig.id)
  )

  return createdProviders.reduce((Acc, Cur, index) => {
    const child =
      index < createdProviders.length ? (
        <Cur value={createdStores[index]} />
      ) : (
        <Cur value={createdStores[index]}>{children}</Cur>
      )
    if (Acc) {
      return <Acc value={createdStores[index - 1]}>{child}</Acc>
    } else {
      return Cur
    }
  }, null)
}
```

However, I have run into many indecipherable TypeScript errors. What am I doing wrong? Surely there is a way of recursively assembling a React component tree?

Answer (score -1):

If the errors are from typescript it's probably because typescript can't follow what you are doing (lost track of `types` somewhere along the way) 
Try writting the code in javascript and see if that gives you any errors.